# Error Parsing Json String into Json Array

Tags: android, json

I am trying to store a Json Response in a String onto a Text file as a Cache. But I am not able to parse it when I read it from the text file.

```
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                 +File.separator
                 +"myDirectory" //folder name
                 +File.separator
                 +"roster.txt"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("School FTB Cache", line);
            line = line + "\n";
        }

    JSONArray rosterJsonArray = new JSONArray(line);
    Log.i("School FTB Cache", rosterJsonArray.toString());
    JSONObject jObject = null;
    Roster roster = new Roster();
    rosterList = new ArrayList<Roster>(rosterJsonArray.length());
    int i=0;

        while(i<rosterJsonArray.length()){
            roster = new Roster();
            jObject = rosterJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.e("roster", jObject.toString());
            roster.setId(Integer.valueOf(jObject.getString("id")));
            roster.setName(jObject.getString("name"));
            roster.setPosition(jObject.getString("position"));
            rosterList.add(i, roster);
            i++;
        }
```

This is the Log Message

```
08-09 01:03:09.703: I/School FTB Cache(18328): [{"position":"DB","id":"1","name":"Ne'Quan Phillips"},{"position":"DB","id":"2","name":"Tony Grimes"},{"position":"LB","id":"3","name":"TJ Taimatuia"},{"position":"LB","id":"4","name":"Steven Lakalaka"},{"position":"WR","id":"5","name":"Billy Ray StutzMaan"}]
08-09 01:03:09.703: W/System.err(18328): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 01:03:09.757: W/System.err(18328):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
08-09 01:03:09.757: W/System.err(18328):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
08-09 01:03:09.773: W/System.err(18328):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
08-09 01:03:09.773: W/System.err(18328):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
08-09 01:03:09.773: W/System.err(18328):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
08-09 01:03:09.773: W/System.err(18328):    at com.boilingstocks.schoolftb.RosterActivity$RosterUpdaterFromCache.doInBackground(RosterActivity.java:135)
08-09 01:03:09.773: W/System.err(18328):    at com.boilingstocks.schoolftb.RosterActivity$RosterUpdaterFromCache.doInBackground(RosterActivity.java:1)
08-09 01:03:09.781: W/System.err(18328):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-09 01:03:09.781: W/System.err(18328):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-09 01:03:09.781: W/System.err(18328):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-09 01:03:09.781: W/System.err(18328):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-09 01:03:09.781: W/System.err(18328):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-09 01:03:09.796: W/System.err(18328):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
08-09 01:03:09.796: W/System.err(18328):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
08-09 01:03:09.796: W/System.err(18328):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
08-09 01:03:09.796: W/System.err(18328):    at com.boilingstocks.schoolftb.RosterActivity$RosterUpdaterFromCache.doInBackground(RosterActivity.java:135)
08-09 01:03:09.796: W/System.err(18328):    at com.boilingstocks.schoolftb.RosterActivity$RosterUpdaterFromCache.doInBackground(RosterActivity.java:1)
08-09 01:03:09.796: W/System.err(18328):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-09 01:03:09.796: W/System.err(18328):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-09 01:03:09.796: W/System.err(18328):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-09 01:03:09.796: W/System.err(18328):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-09 01:03:09.796: W/System.err(18328):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-09 01:03:09.796: W/System.err(18328):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-09 01:03:09.812: W/System.err(18328):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Instead of doing Json parsing yourself, why don't you use a library like Jackson or Gson?

Comment: all of my code currently uses jsonParsing, it is not possible for me atm to use any other library. Isn't there any way to fix this problem ?

Comment: sorry I don't know enough to help you, but I know that by doing your own Json parsing you are just asking for bugs down the road. Also by using an AsyncTask you will run into problems with lifecycle management. Even though it will take some effort I highly recommend you setup Robospice and Spring for Android which will save you a lot of trouble down the road...

Comment: Is `rosterJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)` giving you back a non-null JSONObject every time?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
JSONArray rosterJsonArray = new JSONArray(line);
```

Once your while loop completes, **line is equal to null**. So `new JSONArray(line)` throws a NullPointerException. Plus your while loop resets `line` every time, so `line = line + "\n";` does nothing. You should create another String to put the lines in as you loop through your file.

Answer (score -1):

try changing this line

```
String line = null;
```

to this

```
String line; // or this //String line = "";
```

also initialize it outside the the try block (make it global or local inside the function